# Selenium and TFBuild - Pages never seem to load

Tags: c#, selenium-webdriver, tfs, automated-tests

I have written a number of tests for an MVC application using Selenium and the webdriver.  These work on my dev machine without problem.  We are using the PageFactory design.  Currently I have an explicit wait of 3 seconds (although I have tested up to 10 seconds without change) on page load.

### A relatively simple test is below:
The Test

```cs
    [TestMethod]
    public void Can_Log_In_With_Valid_Credential()
    {
        Pages.LoginPage.Goto();
        var success = Pages.LoginPage.Login(Properties.Settings.Default.UserName,
                                            Properties.Settings.Default.Password);
        Assert.IsTrue(success);
        Pages.HeaderPage.LogOut();
    }
```

### The Page and Related Logic

```cs
public static class Pages
{
    public static LoginPage LoginPage
    {
        get
        {
            var loginPage = new LoginPage();
            PageFactory.InitElements(Browser.Driver, loginPage);
            return loginPage;
        }
    }
}

public class LoginPage : Page
{
    public static string Url = Properties.Settings.Default.DomainAddress + "/Account/Logon";
    public static string PageTitle = "Log On";

    [FindsBy(How = How.Id, Using = "UserName")]
    private IWebElement _userNameBox;

    [FindsBy(How = How.Id, Using = "Password")]
    private IWebElement _passwordBox;

    [FindsBy(How = How.ClassName, Using = "validation-summary-errors")] 
    private IWebElement _validationErrors;

    [FindsBy(How = How.CssSelector, Using = "div#LoginSubmit.signin input")]
    private IWebElement _submitButton;


    public void Goto()
    {
        Browser.Goto(Url);
        
    }

    public bool IsAt()
    {
        return Browser.Title == PageTitle;
    }

    public bool Login(string username, string password)
    {
        try
        {
            _userNameBox.SendKeys(username);
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
            _userNameBox = ((IWebDriver) Browser.Driver).FindElement(By.Id("UserName"), 10);
            _userNameBox.SendKeys(username);
        }
        _passwordBox.SendKeys(password);
        _submitButton.Click();

        return Browser.CurrentUrl != Properties.Settings.Default.DomainAddress + "/Account/Logon";
    }
}
```

The problem arises on the build server.  All of the tests fail with the following:

> Class Initialization method
> KepsPortalMvc.UserAccountManagementTests.Initialize threw exception.
> OpenQA.Selenium.WebDriverTimeoutException:
> OpenQA.Selenium.WebDriverTimeoutException: Timed out after 10 seconds
> --->  OpenQA.Selenium.NoSuchElementException: Unable to locate element: {"method":"id","selector":"UserName"}.

It appears that Firefox is not even loading the page.  I have verified (via Task Manager) that both the webdriver and Firefox are being started by the BuildServiceAccount, however I have not yet found a way of monitoring the network activity (Fiddler is not showing me any HTTP traffic related to that Firefox instance at the very least).

Is there a way (short of putting something like Wireshark on the build server) to let me monitor the WebDriver-Firefox?  It doesn't pop-up as it is run as a different account (I am assuming this is why).

## Clarification

This is working on my Dev machine, but not on the Team Foundation Build server.  We are running Team Foundation on a single server.  The TFBuild Service account is what is currently running the Webdriver and Firefox.  A process entry for Firefox appears in the Task Manager when it runs as does an entry for WebDriver.  A WINDOW for Firefox does NOT.  Fiddler does not show me any traffic for that Firefox instance (but I am unsure if that is because nothing is being loaded at all or it just doesn't show me traffic that is loaded in another users session).

Comment: What version of Selenium? What version of Firefox? Compare the versions of that to what you have locally, any difference? Take a screenshot at a few intervals too (no link to hand for this, but Google can help you), just to verify exactly *what* Firefox is seeing. I would also try running it on an actual user account, not a service account. A user account that has a *desktop* session.

Comment: @Arran Selenium - 2.31.2; Firefox - 20.0.  I have the same locally, no difference.  Is there a simple way I can specify in my test framework what account to run Firefox as?

Comment: Your issue sounds in the version of Firefox. I am not entirely FF20 is supported yet (I've not tested it myself nor have come across anybody using it), however, you can test this theory by downgrading to FF18.

Comment: Just tested.  FF 18 and 19 exhibit the problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A bit of an educated guess here, but it might be that your Test Environment is not set for UI tests. Look at [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee291332.aspx) article on MSDN to see how it should be done.

Secondly, from my experience such a behavior might occur if the build agent runs a different version of msbuild. Make sure they are the same. For example building with VS 2010 and VS 2012 will use different assemblies, and thus provoking different results at runtime.

Comment: Whoa whoa whoa...  So you are telling me that Microsoft expects admins to allow a Service Account to log on automatically locally on startup, disable the screen saver, and remain logged in indefinitely?  They do realize that security people will take issue with that?  Our build server is not set up that way, and barring a miracle never will be.  I will put in a request and make my case but it is unlikely to happen.  We will see though.  On the other point, my version and the build servers version of MSBuild are the same.

Comment: Yup, sucks doesn't it.  You will also find that if you RDP into the box when you disconnect it will leave the user that runs the tests unable to run tests because a lock screen is displayed.  If you want to get in and have a look you'll need to use VNC.

Comment: I don't have a way to verify that the above would fix my issue (however I have not implemented the suggested actions in that MSDN post.  It will take some time for our security section to come to a determination on whether or not we can do this.  Since this answer is the most likely explanation, and it brought to my attention some facts that previously I had not seen regarding CodedUI testing in TF Build, I will award the bounty to this one.  Thanks Zee!

Answer (score 0):

```
OpenQA.Selenium.NoSuchElementException
```

I think this error shows no Element is fpund. It can be caused, that FF lost focus in current window?
How many window have you opened ? or maybe after opening the URL adds either sleep or implicite wait until element isVisible ?

Comment: This is running on our TFS Build machine.  When it runs, there is nothing open, no browsers, no Windows Explorer Windows, nothing.  I have monitored it in Process Explorer previously and I can see that both Firefox and the WebDriver start up.  Those and the MSTest process are the only things being run at that time by the TFBuild Service Account.  Since this is running as the TFBuild Service Account, the window does not pop up in my user session.  I thought Selenium WebDriver was meant to be headless (not needed to be monitored).  If so, why would focus be required?

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you right, you use Selenium to run UI tests on your local dev machine and want them to be run no TFS build machine.

This is not working by default, because the build process is a service without a UI and while it is running in the TFS Build service "session", you will not be able to see it. Therefore you need to setup TFS build to run as interactive process (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh691189.aspx#agent_test), but this would mean that the server is always blocked for it. If it is a hardware machine somewhere, it is possible to turn on the monitor and use it with the build credentials, because it is not locked.

I did something similiar with MS Coded UI Tests and to see if it is working I used my account as build account, so I could open a RDP session to the server, which was the same like for the build. So I could see what was happening during the test, but closing the RDP ended up in failing the test. That's why I always waited for the tests to be finished and than restarted the machine.